# In React - How props are defined initially?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

Suppose a component -

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
    return <h1>Hi, {this.props.name}</h1>
  }
}
```

And the instance of MyComponent -

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <MyComponent name = 'Jack' />
  }
}
```

How can we even define props without defining it in the constructor of MyComponent like -

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}
```

Comment: Because the default constructor in a derived class is `constructor(...args) { super(...args); }`

Comment: Maybe this link will help you https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html

Comment: a suggest for you use [```stateless React component```](https://medium.com/m/global-identity?redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fitnext.io%2Freact-component-class-vs-stateless-component-e3797c7d23ab)